# Python/Tkinter: trying to sample a signal and run a timer simultaneously: program freezes. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to run a timer, updating every second, while sampling a signal (for Raspberry Pi), currently simulating on PC.

The code for the timer works very well by itself, here it comes:

```
def update_timer(self, nap = 1):
    while (self.sw_seconds > 0):
        self.sw_seconds -= nap
        m, s = divmod(self.sw_seconds, 60)
        self.labels["Timer"]['text'] = '%02d:%02d' % (int(m), int(s))
        self.labels["Timer"].after(1000, self.update_timer)
```

Now, the function I use to run simultaneously is:

```
def repeat_function(self,period,f,*args):
    t = time.time()
    while self.bool:
        f(*args)
        t += period
        time.sleep(max(t - time.time(),0))
```

The overall program is lengthy and has been tested to work before calling the repeat_function, but I can fully copy it here if required. Just trying to be concise.

I have tested this configuration by launching the timer (which works by itself) and repeat_function(1.0,print,"Hi there\n"). My program freezes and I have to kill it every time.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the "repeat function"? In real life, it will have to capture a signal sample with a frequency of 10 Hz at least, so I cannot imagine this how this can work when it freezes already when asked to print a statement every second

Comment: time.sleep blocks the main thread, use threads.

Comment: sleep does exactly what it says it does, it puts the whole app to sleep. There are countless questions on this site about using sleep with tkinter.

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` or threads when using `tkinter`, unless you really understand what is going on. Look at `.after` scripts. It's easy to convert a `while` loop into a function that uses `.after` scripts to create a loop. Also when you have `.after(1, ...)`, it runs every 1 millisecond. Most of the time that will just use up your CPU and isn't advisable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. And yes, the `.after(1, ...)` was a typo, I have now corrected it in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, indeed, sleep (put the whole app to sleep) is the wrong tool for the job, with Threading it works well.